# Display all pages - in order

Tags: php, page-template, order

My goal a single-page vertically-scrolling site. I'm using this code to display all the pages one after the other:

```
        <!--  All Pages -->
        <?php
                $pages = get_pages(); 
                foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
                    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); 
                    $title = $page_data->post_title; 
                    $order = $page_data->menu_order;
                    echo "<div id=".$title." data-order=".$order.">".$content."</div>"; 
                }
        ?>
```

I'm new to php, any advice how I can echo the pages in the correct **order**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$pages = get_pages( array('sort_column' => 'menu_order') );
?>
```

[more info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)